# adding words to eclipse Luna spell checker dictionary

Tags: eclipse

I find no way of adding a spell-checker highlighted word, to the spell-checker's dictionary. Is that still possible with eclipse Luna? there used to be a small popover window for doing that....

(I also tried adding a user defined dictionary empty file in `preferences`, didn't help).

Comment: This still works the same way. Not all editors show this popup.

Comment: @matt `I also tried adding a user defined dictionary **empty** file`. Did you try putting words in the file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is possible to add a user dictionary. If you go to `window`->`preferences`:

[image: Enter preferences]

Afterwards go to `general`->`Editors`->`Text Editors`->`Spelling` there is a file input box called `User defined dictionary`

[image: Spelling section]

You can create a regular .txt file **with one word per line**, that will become "ignored" by the editor. My example file is shown below (I've created mine in notepad on windows):

[image: Dictionary.txt file]

When entering the user defined dictionary, I get the ability to add the word to the dictionary when i hold my mouse pointer over the word that is marked. Alternatively, clicking ctrl+1 while on a spell-check-highlighted word, will show the option to do so:

[image: Add to dictionary]

I have tested it in my Eclipse Luna setup, and that seems to work perfectly. I'm using Eclipse Luna (64 bit) version 4.4.1.

**EDIT**: I just tried using pydev in eclipse. In a python project I don't get the popup, where i can click "add to dictionary" however, putting the words in the file still works for me.

Comment: how does one "enter" the user defined dictionary? where does "add to dictionary" hide? thanks for having checked it!

Comment: With Spring STS, I also don't get the pop up.  But adding the words to the dictionary does.

Comment: Just start your answer with "Highlight and Ctrl+1".

Answer (score 7):

Adding as an answer since I don't have the history necessary to comment...

The answer by ArchiFloyd is obviously the correct one. I just wanted to add that "clicking ctrl+1 while on a spell-check-highlighted word" was the magic part for me. If I highlight a word highlighted for misspelling, double-click (or highlight with the keyboard), and then hit CTRL+1 I can see the option to add the word to the dictionary. In various editors (like WikiText), this is the only way I've seen to add a word to the dictionary on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in all editors, e.g. DLTK Ruby from Neon. Then the only way is to add into the file manually.

Comment: In v2020-12, automatically seeing the "add to dictionary" from a mouseover is hit or miss. Sometimes I only get the (dumb) popup telling me the word is spelled incorrectly. Double-click the word and CTRL+1 works 100%.

Comment: Great information, worked perfectly for me.